# How to apply hyperlink to html5 slider element?

Tags: html, button

I have this sliding button:

```
  <div class="royalCaptionItem midTextWithBG textin" data-show-effect="moveleft fade" data-move-offset="231" style="left: 50px; background: url('orange.png'); top: 235px; font-size: 14px !important; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; color: #835503; height: 16px; padding-top: 6px; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); z-index: 1000;">Button</div>
```

How to apply a hyperlink to this button?

Thanks!

Comment: put an `a` inside the div? Bind to the div `click` event?

Comment: change the "button" to an a-tag with display:block?

Answer (score 0):

you can add `onlick` attribute to your div:

```
<div onclick="window.location='http://example.com'" ... >Button</div>
```